# what HTML tags broke page layout?

Tags: xhtml, doctype, html

I want posting in my website to be as rich HTML tags as possible, but safe.

this is tags used in my website:

```
<a> <p> <span> <div> <h1> <h2> <h3> <h4> <h5> <h6> <img> <map> <area> <hr> <br> <br /> <ul> <ol> <li> <dl> <dt> <dd> <table> <tr> <td> <em> <b> <u> <i> <strong> <font> <del> <ins> <sub> <sup> <quote> <blockquote> <pre> <address> <code> <cite> <embed> <object> <param> <strike> <caption> <s> <textarea>
```

my website is in drupal.. and when viewing front page (/node), the layout broken

Comment: Do you honestly believe that a laundry-list of all the tags you used on your site will be sufficient to diagnose your problem?  Post some real code!

Comment: Maybe one of your tags is malformed. <shrug>

Answer (score 0):

What is your DOCTYPE? If your type is XHTML then

```
<hr> and <br>
```

should never be used.

Comment: yes XHTML. I've removed `<hr>`.. but I cannot remove `<br>`. The website is for aggregating feeds.. and feeds from mashable use `<br>`

Comment: Then you might want to consider another DOCTYPE or modify the RSS feed's content before you inject it to your HTML.